# How to test a method with specific file.encoding option?

Tags: java, maven, junit, encoding

In a Maven application I need to test a method with a different encoding and just one of them. The others must use the encoding provided by `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`.

For example:

```java
@Test
public void test1() {...} // regular encoding

@Test
public void test2() {...} // regular encoding

@Test
public void test3() {...} // regular encoding

[...]

@Test
public void testEncoding() {...} // custom encoding!!!
```

I cannot change the encoding with `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "...")` because is cached and I want a procedure that can be *versionable* (i.e. independent by an IDE like IDEA or Eclipse and working for anyone has downloaded the code).

Is there any way via JUnit or Maven plugin to do so?

Comment: The proper way would probably be to abstract away the access to file.encoding (which really, you should try not to rely on: always be explicit with your character sets), and then test by mocking this abstraction so your program can control the encoding at runtime. I'm posting this as a comment as it is a bit hand-wave-y.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding for potential hacks. But, follow @MarkRotteveel's advice and change the code so a specific encoding (or an encoding-aware implementation) can be passed to your code in each test.

Comment: Thank you for the advices @MarkRotteveel and @Joe, my concern is that as the application grows it may be harder to track every single point where `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` affects the results. And I'm also concerned that I am not aware of all the Java APIs using `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`.

Comment: The solution therefor is to write your application in a way that does not rely on the default character set / file.encoding.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1: Optional Charset parameter

You do not need to test your method using the `file.encoding` property.
As you probably know, this property will only set the *DEFAULT* encoding for methods which have an optional encoding/charset parameter.

However, all those methods (without the charset parameter) [are considered a bad habit](https://github.com/policeman-tools/forbidden-apis). That said, overload your methods with an optional parameter `Charset` and the method without this optional parameter should pass in `Charset.defaultCharset()`.

This way you can easily test your methods accordingly.

### Method 2: Maven-Invoker-Plugin

Use the maven-invoker-plugin to create isolated tests in `src/it/<testname>`. Those are fully isolated maven projects.
Examples can be found in almost any maven project. You can pass system arguments via surefire for example.

If this